# How to get the index of this element in an Array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to get the indexes of the elements in the array of production_companies
if the "logo_path" of first company and the last one are null , there may be other companies for which "logo_path" is not null , I want to get their index ,
how can I achieve  this please?

it is a movie indexing application for android
the array of production_companies has a list of companies in it
by default  the logo of the last company on the list is displayed in the app but the condition is it should not be null
but if the last one is null , then get first company on the list which is not null is displayed in the app

but if the first and last both are null , there may be others between first and last which are not , I want to get their index and get their logo displayed in my app

production_companies is the array[object]
logo_path is either string or null , the string example "/q9s9KGhSsFEnpTmLLwprytB3T3d.png"

here is a sample from JSON here the first and last ones are null

```
{"id":68112,"logo_path":"null","name":"Studio 100 Media","origin_country":"DE"}, 
{"id":104638,"logo_path":null,"name":"Studio B Animation","origin_country":""},
{"id":20187,"logo_path":"/bYdzRm9r74bIWlSRKIWZeZyDBFD.png","name":"Flying Bark Productions","origin_country":"AU"},
{"id":45198,"logo_path":"/q9s9KGhSsFEnpTmLLwprytB3T3d.png","name":"Deutscher Filmförderfonds","origin_country":"DE"}, 
{"id":268,"logo_path":"null","name":"FilmFernsehFonds Bayern","origin_country":"DE"},
{"id":2026,"logo_path":"null","name":"FFA","origin_country":"DE"}],
```

```
// Set Studio (production_companies)
            // get the array
            try {
                // get the array
                JSONArray production_companies = jObject.getJSONArray("production_companies");
                // ensure array has at least one entry
                if (production_companies.length() > 0) {
                    // get the last element of the array as JSONObject (offset is length of array - 1)
                    JSONObject lastCompany = production_companies.getJSONObject(production_companies.length() - 1);
                    JSONObject firstCompany = production_companies.getJSONObject(0);


                    // is the "logo_path" property of lastCompany null?
                    if (lastCompany.getString("logo_path") == "null")
                    {
                        // then get first company ... i.e. offset zero
                        movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) +
                                MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (firstCompany, "logo_path", "")); // set the the first production company
                    }


                    // is the "logo_path" property of the firstCompany and  lastCompany are null the get the index of the one which is not null
                    if (lastCompany.getString("logo_path") == "null" && firstCompany.getString("logo_path") == "null")
                    {

                        //  Missing code here
                        
                        
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        // else logo_path is not null, so use lastCompany
                        movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) +
                                MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (lastCompany, "logo_path", "")); // set the last production company
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {}
```

```
production_companies array[object]

name             string

id               integer

logo_path        string or null

origin_country   string
```

Comment: Can you please add expected output?

Comment: Thanks , the expexted output is the logo ( .png file ) of the company which has logo path but it is not the first or last on the list

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. I think adding a complete input/expected output example can make things more clear here.

Comment: the array of production_companies has a list of companies in it

Comment: it is a movie indexing application for android

Comment: the deafult is to get the logo of the last company on the list but the condition is it should not be null

Comment: but if the last one is null , then get first company on the list which is not null

Comment: It will be great if you can supply an example. Input JSON & expected output JSON. It will be easier for people to answer.

Comment: but if the first and last both are null , there may be other in between first and last which are not , I want to get their index and get their logo displayed in my app

Comment: I already posted JSON example it is from themoviedb.org

Comment: the production_companies  is the array

Comment: production_companies is the array[object]

Comment: logo_path is either string or null , the string example "/q9s9KGhSsFEnpTmLLwprytB3T3d.png"

Comment: No, in your example, logo_path is null, "null", and a String.  null and "null" are not the same thing.

Comment: I mean the value of logo_path is either a string like "/q9s9KGhSsFEnpTmLLwprytB3T3d.png" or null , you can check this and you will see what I mean https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-movie-details

Comment: Do you know how to add a library to your project?

Comment: no unfortunately  I  don't know , sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to add a library, add:

```
implementation group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.5.0'
```

and you can then do something like:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.DocumentContext;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option;

...

Configuration cf = Configuration.builder().options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS).build();
DocumentContext ctx = JsonPath.using(cf).parse(moviesJson);

String firstLogo = ctx.read("$.[0].logo_path");
String lastLogo = ctx.read("$.[-1].logo_path");

// handle "null" vs null
if( firstLogo.equals("null"))
    firstLogo = null;

if( lastLogo.equals("null"))
    lastLogo = null;

// use last logo if it's set
if( lastLogo != null )
    movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) + lastLogo);
else if( firstLogo != null )  // last logo isn't set, see if we can use first
    movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) + firstLogo);
else { // both are null - find the first non-null one
    List<String> someOtherLogo = ctx.read("$.[?(@.logo_path!='null' && @.logo_path!=null)].logo_path");
    // there may be more than one - get the first one
    movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) + someOtherLogo.get(0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks , yes I apply this in android manifest , and give it a try , I think I can do this

Comment: I mean build.gradle

Comment: I imported successfully , now I will apply

Comment: the issue is I cannot apply movie.setStudioUrl(baseUrl + MizLib.getStudioUrlSize (mContext) +
        MizLib.getStringFromJSONObject (firstCompany, "logo_path", ""));  instead of    System.out.println("someOtherLogo is " + someOtherLogo.get(0));

Comment: I compiled and run the app, but it doesn't return the logos for some reason

Comment: At this point then it's debugging.  You'll need to see what values you're getting in both the input (i.e. the JSON) and what are you pulling in the values.  Specifically I'd find out what values are contained in the three variables `firstLogo`, `lastLogo`, and `someOtherLogo`.  Are the values what you expect?  If so, are you building the `studioUrl` correctly?  You'll need to log or debug these values to see where the issue is.

Comment: Ok I will follow along with that, I will try to get see what it is

Comment: I think the the firstlogo and lastlogo and  someOtherLogo  , should be JSONObject instead of String

Comment: could this be due to java 1.7

Comment: I set breakpoint at firstLogo = null; but the it does not reach the breakpoint which means we miss something here

Comment: I set break point at `String lastLogo = ctx.read("$.[-1].logo_path");`

Comment: jayway library is not capable of parsing JSONArray

Answer (score 1):

One thing that makes your code problematic is that you've mixed together code responsible for parsing JSON with business logic. If you separate those, the solution will be much simpler.

What I would suggest then is to do it in two steps.

1. Parse json into POJO classes. Looking at your data it could just be a list (or array) of companies. Company being simple java class. This step you could have done automatically using for instance GSON library.
2. Once you have all the data in java array with objects, iterate it to find the one that you're interested in (in your case having non-null logo path).

Comment: I have to be honest , I'm in very early stages of learning how to code

Comment: I tired to use some other methods but I failed , because it was not clear enough